# NHIbernate QueryOver detached criteria and Any clause

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following in subquery which is failing:

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Product>()
                .Where(x => x.ProductCategories.Any(y => y.Categgory == parameter.Category));
```

I get an error for the Any statement:

```
Unrecognised method call: System.Linq.Enumerable:Boolean Any
```

How would I update the above restriction for QueryOver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ProductCategory productCategory = null;
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Product>()
  .JoinAlias(product => product.ProductCategories, () => productCategory)              
  .Where(() => productCategory.Category.Id == parameter.Category.Id);
```

What's type of Category? If this is an entity:

```
productCategory.Category.Id == parameter.Category.Id
```

If this is base property:

```
productCategory.Category == parameter.Category
```

Is it many-to-many relation? (Product and Category)

```
Category category = null;
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Product>()
  .JoinAlias(product => product.Category, () => category)            
  .Where(() => category.Id == parameter.Category.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ProductCategory productCategory = null;
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Product>()
  .JoinAlias(product => product.ProductCategories, () => productCategory)  
  .Where(Subqueries.WhereExists(CatExistsQuery())


private QueryOver<ProductCategory , ProductCategory > CatExistsQuery(<your type> parameter)
        {
            ProductCategory _innerCat = null;

            var query = (QueryOver<ProductCategory , ProductCategory >)Session
                        .QueryOver(() => _innerCat )
                        .Where(() => _productCategory.Id== _innerCat.Id)
                        .And (innerCat.Id == parameter.Category.Id)

            return query ;
        }
```